# Sharepoint 2013 - how to attach document to a document library as anonymous user

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a document library on Sharepoint2013 site. I want anonymous users to access this list and can upload any documents they want after specifying their email address. I directed to list settings and allow anonymous access on permissions like below.

```
Name            Type            Permission Levels
Anonymous Users Anonymous Users Add Items, Edit Items, Delete Items, View Items
```

Right now, anonymous users can access the document library without a problem. Those users can click save button without selecting a document, this is working and a record exists. However, when a document is uploaded by anonymous users, when save button is clicked, the user is automatically directed to a login page, asking for credentials, without saving the document. What I want is that anonymous users would upload any document to the document library as well, they should not need to log in.

I appreciate if anyone helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anonymous users are unable to upload documents into SharePoint libraries by default, so you would have to create a webpart and use the RunWithElevatedPrivileges method to upload files into a document library.

You can find the webpart's code here:

http://andreaswijayablog.blogspot.com.br/2014/04/sharepoint-2013-anonymous-access-add.html